# Conditional check in an array in jolt

Tags: jolt

I'm trying to write a if condition in array but not able to get the expected output.
I'm looking for:
if serviceType = "Remote Collect",
then shipments.details.containers.containerItems.weight = waypoint.inventory.inventory.handling_units.remote_weight
else shipments.details.containers.containerItems.weight = waypoint.inventory.inventory.weight

Input :
{
"serviceType": "Remote Collect",
"serviceLevel": "STANDARD_SERVICE",
"shipments": [
{
"details": [
{
"containers": [
{
"containerID": "container1",
"containerType": "Box1",
"contentDescription": "Fruits",
"quantity": 7,
"containerItems": [
{
"itemID": "strawberries",
"quantity": "1",
"itemDescription": "strawberries bag",
"weight": 23
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me a full JSON input? I think you missed the "waypoint" object. If you did not miss then where is your "waypoint.inventory.inventory.handling_units.remote_weight".

Comment: @PushprajSingh : Question is in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562097/conditional-check-inside-an-array-in-jolt. Appreciate any help here .