# Conditional check inside an array in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to do if condition in array but not able to get the expected output.

If  **`"serviceType"` = `"Remote Collect"`**,

then **`shipments.details.container.containerItems.weight` =
`waypoint.inventory.inventory.handling_units.remote_weight`**

else **`shipments.details.container.containerItems.weight` = `waypoint.inventory.inventory.weight`**

Input JSON:

```json
{
  "serviceType": "Remote Collect",
  "serviceLevel": "STANDARD_SERVICE",
  "shipments": [
    {
      "details": [
        {
          "containers": [
            {
              "containerID": "container1",
              "containerType": "Box1",
              "contentDescription": "Fruits",
              "quantity": 7,
              "containerItems": [
                {
                  "itemID": "strawberries",
                  "quantity": "1",
                  "itemDescription": "strawberries bag",
                  "weight": 23
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "spec": {
      "serviceType": {
        "Remote Collect": {
          "@(2,shipments[0].freightTotals.weight)": "total_handling_units.remote_weight",
          "@(2,serviceType)": "service_type_tmp",
          "#4": "task_type_id",
          "#true": "remoteWeight_tmp"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,shipments[0].freightTotals.weight)": "total_weight",
          "@(2,serviceType)": "service_type_tmp",
          "#4": "task_type_id",
          "#false": "remoteWeight_tmp"
        }
      },
      "shipments": {
        "0": {
          "details": {
            "*": {
              "containers": {
                "*": {
                  "containerItems": {
                    "*": {
                      "itemDescription": [
                          "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].description",
                            "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].name"
                            
                      ],
                      "remoteWeight_tmp": {
                        "#true": {
                          "weight": [
                            "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].remote_weight"
                            ]
                        },
                        "#false": {
                          "weight": [
                            "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].weight"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "itemID": [
                          "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].external_id"
                      ],
                      "quantity": [
                          "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].original_quantity"
                      ],
                      "#true": [
                    "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].pending"
                  ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "operation": "shift"
  }
]
```

Actual Output:

```json
{
  "remoteWeight_tmp": "true",
  "service_type_tmp": "Remote Collect",
  "task_type_id": "4",
  "way_points": [
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "inventory": [
            {
              "description": "strawberries bag",
              "external_id": "strawberries",
              "name": "strawberries bag",
              "original_quantity": "1",
              "pending": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "remoteWeight_tmp": "true",
  "service_type_tmp": "Remote Collect",
  "task_type_id": "4",
  "way_points": [
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "inventory": [
            {
              "description": "strawberries bag",
              "external_id": "strawberries",
              "name": "strawberries bag",
              "original_quantity": "1",
              "pending": "true",
              "handling_units": {
                "remote_weight": 23
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse me it's a bit confusing and hard to follow, first of all I couldn't understand why doubled the content of the inner array ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: I have made the changes in the jolt spec in the inner array.  basically, all I want is the if condition in the inner most array,

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: I'm trying a lot of things but not able to figure out. Really appreciate your help here.

Comment: But there are no such variables beginning with `waypoint.inventory.inventory....` those you want to use for assignment

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: If you see my expected output, there is a nested array :                          "way_points": [
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "inventory": [
            {
              "description": "strawberries bag",
              "external_id": "strawberries",
              "etc"...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    } . So, if my input has "serviceType" = "Remote Collect", then my ouput should have :waypoints.inventory.inventory.handling_units.remote_weight

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : can I have your email Id so we can have this conmmunication faster?

Comment: but there's already no such attribute such as `remote_weight` that you already hardcoding it, and you can do the others like that.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: but this is inside the nested array , I tried something like :  "spec": {
      "serviceType": {
        "Remote Collect": {
          "@(5,shipments[0].details.containers.containerItems.weight)": "way_points[0].inventory[&3].inventory[&1].total_handling_units.remote_weight",

        }, But this is giving error. Not able to proceed. I know I'm doing something wrong, but not understanding what is that

Comment: What will be the expected output whenever "serviceType" != "Remote Collect" ?

Comment: {
  "remoteWeight_tmp": "true",
  "service_type_tmp": "Remote Collect",
  "task_type_id": "4",
  "way_points": [
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "inventory": [
            {
              "description": "strawberries bag",
              "external_id": "strawberries",
              "name": "strawberries bag",
              "original_quantity": "1",
              "pending": "true",              
                "weight": 23              
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}

Comment: So, if you see my above message, if serviceType != Remote Collect, then the expected output will be :  waypoints.inventory.inventory.weight .shipments.details.container.containerItems.weight= waypoints.inventory.inventory.weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dive deep upto the innermost array(`containerItems`) and tile the attributes such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*T*": "&(0,1)_t&(0,2)_tmp",
      "#true": "remoteWeight_tmp",
      "#4": "task_type_id",
      "shipments": {
        "*": {
          "details": {
            "*": {
              "containers": {
                "*": {
                  "containerItems": {
                    "*": {
                      "itemD*": ["way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&1].d&(0,1)", "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&1].name"], // to name double attribute by the same value
                      "itemID": "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&1].external_id",
                      "q*": "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&1].original_q&(0,1)", // replacement for the 1st asterisk from the 0th(current) level
                      "#true": "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&1].pending",
                      "@8,serviceType": { // conditional follows
                        "Remote Collect": {
                          "@2,weight": "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&2].handling_units.remote_weight" // grab the value after going 2 levels up
                        },
                        "*": { // else case
                          "@2,weight": "way_points[0].inventory[0].inventory[&2].weight"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // sort the results in alphabetical order based on the elements' keys
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]